# Importing 10 bit RAW DNG files into python without demosaic algorithm (I want the raw red channel data)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, camera

I want to import the raw, DNG image sensor data into python without any mosaicing. I have tried the following code using pyraw:

```
with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(output_bps=8,demosaic_algorithm=None,output_color = rawpy.ColorSpace.Adobe)
```

But I am noticing a problem:

The camera I am using has a RGGB bayer filter and is 10 bits per pixel, so we should only expect red data from every second pixel in every row starting at row 0 column 0. When I look at rgb[:,:,0] (red channel), I am seeing data in adjacent rows and columns, indicating some sort of post processing I assume. I have used the possprocess function in rawpy, however, I assumed that as I specified no demosaic algorithm we shouldn't have adjacent red pixels.

Any thoughts?